# Waiting in transit zone until Schengen visa is valid

Tags: visas, schengen, paris, uzbek-citizens

I'm from Uzbekistan. I have a Schengen visa from France. This visa is valid from 9 Sep 2015 until 3 Oct 2015.

But I have booked a ticket from Tashkent to Paris on 8 Sep. The time of arriving to Paris is at 19.30pm on 8 Sep.

May I go to Paris 19.30pm on 8 Sept and wait in transit zone until 00.00 9 Sept, then go to passport control to enter Paris?

Comment: We have a very similar question regarding flying to Frankfurt. Even if some of the response is specific for Frankfurt, the issue with the airline also apply to you. Even if you might have the option to wait in Paris, you are likely to be denied boarding by the airline since you don't have a valid visa for your destination. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46211/arriving-at-night-before-schengen-visa-valid-date

Comment: Please read this http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten/53412#53412 with special emphasis on the "History" section.