# Schengen Visa Expiry Date and Date of Return Journey

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, overstaying

My Schengen Visa expires on 10th January 2017. It is an 80 days visa for family visit purpose. Now my return journey from Dusseldorf to Mumbai is via Zurich. I am departing Dusseldorf on 10th January 2017 at 20:30 Hrs (CET). Reaching Zurich on 21:30 Hrs (CET). My flight for Mumbai from Zurich is the next day (11th January 2017) morning 9:45 Hrs (CET).

My question is: Doesn't it look like I am overstaying my visa period? But is it really a problem as I am returning back to the country I am a passport holder of (India)?

Comment: Why not travel one day earlier, so that you leave the Schengen area on January 10th?

Comment: That's because I have already booked my ticket and then applied for Visa. Now the consulate has issued visa with the valid until date: 10th January 2017.

Comment: 10th Feb? you mean 10th Jan?

Comment: 10th January yes. Thanks for correcting me. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by @pnuts, yes it is a problem.

I see two ways out:

1. Contact the consulate (or the place that issued your visa) and ask for a correction of the dates on your visa. If you handed in the itinerary with your application they could/should have noticed that.
2. ZRH has an airside transit hotel. Try to have your luggage checked through from DUS to Mumbai and enter the extra-Schengen zone of ZRH airport before midnight (before 10:30 p.m. when security closes to be precise!) and stay in the transit hotel. (Given your flight times there's not much leeway for delays here!) 
   I have written more about doing this the other way round in [Arriving in Zurich the night before Schengen visa validity begins](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/72111/32134) and there you find contact details for the hotel. Absolutely check with them (they are responsive) whether you can enter the area the night before with a boarding pass for the next day, as that might foil this option.

Or simply change your flight dates as pointed out by @AliAwan and others. On the long run the cost is much lower than having an overstay in your history for future applications.

Comment: I agree! That was a superb analysis. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: tbh in your place I would not rely on the solution 2. times are too short and you risk a lot when there is a simple delay as can happen every day! @Honigbiene

Comment: Better I will just go and ask the Consulate if they can change the date. Or i will rebook my ticket. :-/

Answer (score 8):

> Yes, you are overstaying your Schengen visa for 1 day.

Although you are finishing your Schengen stay  in Dusseldorf , but you exit from Zurich next day (11 January 2017) which is actually your last stop in Schengen Zone.

There could be  serious consequences for your next Schengen visa , also you are staying 80 days there and traveling back on 11 January 2017 . There is  plenty of time now to change your flight date before the visa expiration date.

Because you must have mentioned in your itinerary to Schengen consulate/embassy that you last date of departure is 10 January 2017, it is always feasible to exit before expiration date.

**Options** :

1 Either change your travel date before 10 January 2017

2 Or contact embassy/consulate to extend visa for another day.

Comment: Is there any workaround other than rescheduling my flight ticket? Can I apply for a transit visa? Or a one day Schengen Visa on top of my existing Schengen visa which I have received?

Comment: No @Honigbiene zurich is schengen country, they will not allow for another transit only for staying in zurich. thats not schengen rule

Comment: Ahh Ohkay. I did not know that. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @Honigbiene welcome anytime, come back again for new questions:)

Comment: Sure. Thank you once again for your guidance.

Answer (score 7):

> Doesn't it look like I am overstaying my visa period?

Yes.

> But is it really a problem as I am returning back to the country I am a passport holder of (India)?

Yes.

Comment: What are my options? Should I contact the consulate? Or should I take a transit visa of Zürich airport. For Indians they say they don't need a Transit Visa.

Comment: Probably I should change my flights. You are right.