# What happens if flight reaches Germany 4-5 hours before Visa start date

Tags: schengen, business-travel

Suppose my visa start date is 15-Aug-2019, and I book a flight that lands in Germany on the 14-Aug-2019 at 22:00 PM, will they allow me in?

Comment: You wouldn’t be allowed to board the aircraft. Possible duplicate of [Arriving at night before Schengen visa valid date?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46211/arriving-at-night-before-schengen-visa-valid-date)